# How to make Git Bash forget about previosly cloned SVN projects?

Tags: bash, git, svn, gitlab

During experiments with SVN to Git migration, I cloned several SVN-projects into local Git repositories (git svn clone). Then I added a remote origin (git remote add origin) and successfully imported the projects to Gitlab (git push --all origin).

Then I deleted those projects, both the location of cloned projects on my hard drive and in Gitlab. And then I repeated the procedure all over for the same SVN projects.

And now it looks like: both physical location on the local hard drive and, correspondingly, the Gitlab projects are created empty. Git Bash console reports: Everything up-to-date.

My understanding: since I deleted physical copies, Git Bash somehow has memory about the previosly cloned projects and their states.

My question: how to make Git Bash forget about the previously cloned SVN projects?

Comment: Git bash has no memory. Show (the commands) of what you did, which output you expected and explain how that is different from what you are perceiving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Git BASH is reporting that "Everything is up to date", it means that the local repository is completely in sync with the remote repository.

If you perform a `git log` command from BASH, it will tell you the history of commits. Check to see if this commit history is the same as the commit history of the repository form which you cloned. If it is, then everything is working. If not, you have not properly cloned the remote repository. Perhaps you cloned an empty repository instead?

Furthermore, a listing of Git commits in the log will give you a better idea of what you have locally. It might help you track down the root of your problem.